# SQL-Obter codigo dos empregados que particparam em todos projectos

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query

Tenho as seguintes tabelas Empregado(EmpNum ,Nome) Projecto(ProjNum,Nome) e Atribuicao (EmpNum ,ProjNum,Funcao)

Queria construir uma query em que me devolva o numero de empregado(EmpNum ) que por meio da Atribuicao participaram em todos os Projectos. Tentei fazer algo como:

```
Select A.ProjNum
From Atribuicao A
Where A.EmpNum in (Select E.EmpNum From Empregado E)
```

Mas é insuficiente... e nao estou conseguir chegar ao resultado.

Comment: Pesquise por divisão em algebra relacional , simplificando um not exists em outro not exists , solução clássica , eu tinha um exemplo , perdi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que Motta sugeriu foi:

```
SELECT E.Nome
FROM Empregado E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT P ProjNum
                  FROM Project P
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT A.ProjNum
                                    FROM Atribuicao A
                                    WHERE A.ProjNum = P.ProjNum
                                    AND A.EmpNum = E.EmpNum))
```